# Storing LatLng using Android Realm

Tags: android, realm

What is there cleaner whay of storing a RealmObject that contains a Google's LatLng object int Realm?

```
Area {
Latlat coord;
String name
}
```

Comment: store them as Latitude and Longitude by using `coord.getLat()` and `coord.getlang()` both returns a `double`

Comment: I think this what i'm gonna do. Will need some heavy refactor though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might seem natural to save the data as an object

```
LatLng { 
 double lat; 
 double lng; 
}
```

remember that Realm is an object store - if you create an object, it will be stored in a table (entity). As suggested by Mohammed Ra (in the comment above), you should store an object which contains the fields latitude and longitude, both as double

```
class Area extends RealmObject {
  double lat; 
  double lng;
  String name;
  ...
}
```

This solution also improves the performance of queries involving the coordinates - in which case you should put `@Index` annotation on them.

Comment: Realm is not noSql database, not relational

Answer (score 0):

You can create Model like this which is in java :

```
public class ActionDataModel extends RealmObject
{
  private LocationDataModel targetLatLong;

  @NonNull
  public LatLng getTargetLatLong()
  {
    return new LatLng(targetLatLong.getLatitude(), targetLatLong.getLongitude());
  }

  public void setTargetLatLong(@NonNull LatLng targetLatLong)
  {
    this.targetLatLong = new LocationDataModel(targetLatLong);
  }

}
```

Here is the parent model which is in kotlin :

```
open class LocationDataModel(latLng: LatLng? = null)
: RealmObject() {
  var latitude = latLng?.latitude
  var longitude = latLng?.longitude
}
```