# How to store latitude and longitude in realm?

Tags: realm

I am totally new in android. I am using GPS tracking in my application using realm. I am successful to find latitude and longitude but i don't know how to store latitude and longitude in realm. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can make your own model, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504576/storing-latlng-using-android-realm. Or you can save `Double` Longitude and Latitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store data in realm you need a class that extends `RealmObject`.
You can do as follow:

```
public class MyLatLng extends RealmObject {
   private double lat;
   private double lng;

   public void setLat(double val) { this.lat = val; }
   public void setLng(double val) { this.lng = val; }
}
```

Then for storing it, you need to initialize a new instance as follow:

```
MyLatLng instance = new MyLatLng();
instance.setLat(*yourLat*);
instance.setLng(*yourLng*);
```

After that, you can finally store it in Realm:

```
Realm.init(context);
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(instance); 
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can do it.